# Imagemagick - use mogrify only for files with colorspace CMYK

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I need to use a jpg conversion script only for CMYK colorspace files. The problem is that there are a lot of jpg files (colospace sRGB and CMYK) in the folder. I want to use the mogrify function. I've already created a general script to change all files in a folder. I need to create a filter to make the script work only for JPG with CMYK files

```
cd "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q16-HDRI\"
magick mogrify -profile c:\test\profile\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile "c:\test\profile\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm" -quality 80 c:\test\*.jpg
```

Comment: mogrify cannot filter on colorspace and only process CMYK. You will need to write a script loop that tests for colorspace and then does a convert on the CMYK files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the effect I needed. I found a similar script and edited it according to my needs. I am not a programmer so sorry for the syntax. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S *.jpg') do call :process "%%I"
goto :eof

:process
C:\Progra~1\ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q16-HDRI\magick identify -verbose %1 | find /c /i "Colorspace: CMYK" > c:\test\temp.txt
set /p count=<c:\test\temp.txt
del c:\test\temp.txt
if %count%==1 (
C:\Progra~1\ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe mogrify -profile c:\test\profile\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile c:\test\profile\sRGBColorSpaceProfile.icm -quality 80 "%~dpn1.jpg"
)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3):

As Fred (@fmw42) says, `mogrify` can't restrict its processing based on image type like that. However, it *can* work with a list of filenames. So, if `filelist.txt` looks like this:

```
image32.jpg
image43.jpg
...
```

you can get `mogrify` to resize those files like this:

```
magick mogrify -resize 640x480 @filelist.txt
```

So, now the issue is how to generate a list of CMYK files. I can't tell you exactly how to do that on **Windows** but I can tell you how to get started and hopefully you can work out the rest.

If you run this command, it will print a line with each image's colourspace and filename into a file:

```
magick identify -format "%[colorspace]:%f\r\n" *.jpg > filelist.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
CMYK:a.jpg
sRGB:b.jpg
```

where:

- `%[colorspace]` is the image's colourspace
- `:` is just a separator that I chose at random
- `%f` is the image filename
- `\r\n` are Windows CR+LF line endings.

You then need to select only lines starting `CMYK` and discard the first field and your job is done. In Linux/macOS, I would use:

```
magick identify -format "%[colorspace]:%f\n" *.jpg | grep "^CMYK" | cut -d: -f2 > filelist.txt
```

You can get `grep` and `cut` for **Windows**, but there are probably other (more native) ways of selecting lines in **Windows** using `FOR` loops like [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: Mark thanks for your time, but I just got a solution.